# How to apply the search function on a many2many field in Odoo?

Tags: odoo

I have been working on developing modules in Odooo8. I have a  many2many field that is being filtered through the search function .The scenario is that the many2many field has widget="many2many_checkboxes", now I want to get all the records based on the checkbox selection. I tried this:

```
 ramdan_records = self.env['hr.contract'].search([('analytic_account_id','in', self.stable_id)])
```

On doing this got following error:

```
AssertionError: Invalid value account.analytic.account(1, 2, 3) in domain term
```

I want to fetch all records matching the criteria. Can I have some guidance on this. Thanks n Regards

Answer (score 4):

Try to write ids in stable ids.

```
ramdan_records = self.env['hr.contract'].search([('analytic_account_id','in', self.stable_id.ids)])
```

It might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

replace with `self.stable_id` as `self.stable_id.id` its very difficult to say the answer without seeing your code. I am also faced the same problem like yours.